# snowflake-connector-python execute_async() cancelling query on close: "No async queries seem to be running, deleting session"

Tags: aws-lambda, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using the snowflake-connector-python package (v3.0.1 on Python 3.9; same behavior on an older version) to make asynchronous calls from AWS Lambda to Snowflake. I am using .execute_async() to execute the query. The connection is then closed. Per the [documentation and examples](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/python-connector/python-connector-example#label-python-connector-asynchronous-query-examples), closing the connection should not affect the query status.

```
try:
    sfq = con.cursor()
    sfq.execute_async(query)
  except Exception as err:

...

  sfq.close()
  con.close()
```

Here is the main issue. We have this solution deployed in an AWS DEV instance and it works as expected. When the connection is closed, the connector detects this and keeps the session alive. CloudWatch shows the following log entry indicating as such:

`There are 1 async queries still running, not deleting session`

In the QA instance, it shows the following as the query is cancelled upon close:

`No async queries seem to be running, deleting session`

The Lambda function matches 1:1 (QA imported from DEV), the Snowflake instances, DEV and QA, are zero copy clones of PROD. So as far as I can tell, things match 1:1. The only potential difference is the AWS accounts/instances being different, but I'm not confident that would result in the behavior we're seeing. Any suggestions on where to look next?

Comment: Is the Stored procedure taking the same amount of time on both DEV and QA? The log messages indicate that in one case the async query did not finish, while on the second case it finished.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your `SnowflakeConnection` is created but this could be happening because of the behavior of `ABORT_DETACHED_QUERY`session parameter if set to `True` [[docs]](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters#abort-detached-query) .

It is also called out in the async documentation [async documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/python-connector/python-connector-example#performing-an-asynchronous-query) noting that

> To perform asynchronous queries, you must ensure the
> ABORT_DETACHED_QUERY configuration parameter is FALSE (default value).
>
> Snowflake automatically closes connections after a period of time
> (default: 5 minutes), which orphans any active queries. If the value
> is TRUE, Snowflake terminates these orphaned queries, which can impact
> asynchronous queries.